# Video streaming using HTML 5

Tags: video, streaming, html5-video

I have question about video streaming using html 5 video attribute, I want to create a page when visitor can watch movies (VoD) everything is easy but … original video format on server is MJPEG with high resolution. HTML demand for example ogg or H.264 format so I need to convert my video, I don’t know how to do it. A streaming server is written in c++, I want to convert video dynamically on server site. But this is not the worst problem,
I want also to do something like : When user stop the video player, he can see current frame with original resolution (MJPEG like original movie on a server), so maybe somebody face to similar problem, I will be glad for every advice.

Comment: You might need to convert it to the required formats before you upload them to your server. That way there is less load on the server due to no need to convert them on the fly. [http://caniuse.com/#search=video%20format]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for something like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org).

Answer (score 1):

libx264 is supposed to deliver the best video quality.
You can choose between different encoding profiles. There are low
lattency settings which only rely on past frames. This gives lower encoding efficiency.

For best performance and lowest bandwidth you should use a high quality profile that also takes into account future frames.

Note that I would still cache the converted video disk space is cheap nowadays.

I guess its easy to extract the still frame from the MJPEG stream (its a stream of JPEG files after all).